# How to count occurrences of this dataset in SQL?

Tags: sql

Hello I need to know the sql code on this question:

How many students did not participate for the first time the exam DBS21 in periode 201101?

| studentnr | examcode | periode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | DBS21 | 201001 |
| 101 | DBS21 | 201003 |
| 101 | DBS21 | 201101 |
| 101 | ICB21 | 201001 |
| 102 | ICB21 | 201001 |
| 103 | DBS21 | 201001 |
| 103 | DBS21 | 201003 |
| 104 | DBS21 | 201101 |
| 104 | ICB21 | 201003 |
| 105 | DBS21 | 201003 |
| 105 | DBS21 | 201101 |
| 105 | ICB21 | 201003 |

The answer should be 2 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional aggregation approach to achieve the desired result -

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studentnr) - SUM(CASE WHEN periode = 201101 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM your_table;
```

This query will perfectly work when there is no duplication for periode = 201101 for a single studentnr which is as per your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment Ankir, I'm getting -9 as an answer.

Comment: It's because you want `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studentnr) - COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN periode = 201101 and examcode = 'DBS21' THEN studentnr END)`

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code helps:

```
select count(*)
from
(select a.studentnr, min(a.periode) as min_period
 from
 (select *
  from your_table_name
  where studentnr in ( select distinct studentnr
                       from your_table_name
                       where examcode = "DBS21" and
                             periode = "201101"
                     ) and
  examcode = "DBS21")a
group by 1)b
where b.min_period <> "201101";
```

Output: 2